# How to label 3D plot with specific variables

Tags: plotting

I have a plot of a function depending on two variables called `l2` and `l3`. However, I would like to label the axes of the plot with $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$. I tried

```
Plot3D[{(Bg*l2*l3), 0}, {l2, 0, 10}, {l3, 0, 10}, 
AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Subscript[\[Lambda], 2]], 
HoldForm[Subscript[\[Lambda], 3]]}]
```

but it doesn't work, the label stays `l2` and `l3`.

How can I get the correct labelling? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a list of three elements for the `AxesLabel` in `Plot3D`.

```
Plot3D[{(Bg*l2*l3), 0}, {l2, 0, 10}, {l3, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {Subscript[\[Lambda], 2], Subscript[\[Lambda], 3], Null}]
```

[image]

Please note that since the value of `Bg` is not given, the graph is obviously incorrect. And the `HoldForm` is not necessary here since there is nothing could be evaluated.

Comment: Do you perhaps also know how to label the ticks on the axes with 10^3 instead of 1000?

Comment: Error: "A tick position in the value of the Ticks option should be a number."

Comment: @LCF Sorry, I misread your question...`Plot[0, {x, 0, 2 10^3}, Ticks -> {{{1000, HoldForm[10^3]}}, {-1, 1}}]` this will work